# OpenGL - animating the data of the vector as separate frames

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have the output of calculation result (basically the certain amount of cuboids in the certain rotations) stored in the std::vector Box, based on which I am creating the model matrices for OpenGl visualization:

```
    std::vector<glm::mat4> modelMatrices;
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < Box.number_of_cuboids(); i++)
    {
            float rx, ry, rz, teta;
            Box.cuboid(i).get_rotation(rx, ry, rz, teta, j);
            float x, y, z;
            Box.cuboid(i).position(x, y, z, j);
            glm::mat4  model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(x, y, z))
                                 * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), teta, glm::vec3(rx, ry, rz))
                               * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(
            Box.cuboid(i).width(), Box.cuboid(i).length(j), Box.cuboid.height()));
            modelMatrices.push_back(model);
        }
    }
```

and I can successfully visualise them like that:

```
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window, Box.size_x(), Box.size_y(), Box.size_z());
        glClearColor(0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* shaders part <...>*/

        for (int32_t i = 0; i < modelMatrices.size(); i++)
        {
            ourShader.setMat4("model", modelMatrices[i]);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

My problem is that Box is already the final output of the calculations. I would like to see the all the iterations steps, so basically what I would like to do:

```
function ManyCalculations (std::vector<Box>)
{
   at every iteration I save the current status Box in the vector, i.e. 
}
```

so basically after lets say 10000 iterations I end up with the same amount of Box elements, and now I would like to run such vector as frames/animation(video?) in my OpenGl function, and so I could see the evolving calculation of the contents.

Comment: Do you want each box to appear after a frame ?

Comment: Yes. Each Box would represent one frame. Each new Box in the vector can have a minor change (or be identical, actually). In the output I would like to see "video" where each frame(Box) is visualized for 1 second, for example, and I can see the differences.

Comment: Also maybe there is a better way to achieve what I want (to see how the shapes in the box are changing). The number of the shapes will never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate your objects with each frame you would need to keep updating you Vertex Buffer Objects(VBOs).

Either you can keep adding each new box with a frame or change the Translation Matrices.

Than set the new data in your VBO before drawing.

If you know the maximum size of your data in that case you can build a large VBO and keep updating the data with glBufferSubData.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Box.number_of_cuboids() * sizeof(cuboids), &Box[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: 1)  glm::mat4  model[i] should be updated accordingly to the new box  - noted;
2) building large VBO - noted;
3) But how to re-set  the new data in your VBO before drawing? I am setting VBO just one time before   calling "while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))"

Comment: Ok anyway I understood what I need to do  - Dynamic Update of VBOs - thank you.